# What is a good alternative to OpenMapTiles?

Tags: openstreetmap, vector-tiles, openmaptiles

I want migrate image tiles (osm2pgsql, mapnik, etc.) to vector tiles. I tried OpenMapTiles. But the documentation is bad. To start a local test system is no problem, but create a own server and own styling, is very laborious. What is a good alternative to OpenMapTiles?

Comment: https://github.com/systemed/tilemaker